# Several models showing "Data processing failed" shortly after launching the creation of a model

Tags: data-processing, microsoft-translator, mt

We have been using Custom Translator for about a year and we are trying to retrain a few of our existing models with more data. After uploading all the data, selecting it and launching the creation of a model, all 6 of the models in question in different language combinations display "Data processing failed" and nothing else. The models have all between 300,000 and 800,000 sentences of parallel data in them and the data all comes from similar sources.
What is the cause of this and how do we bypass it?

Thank you.